# Does an analytical solution exist for the value of integral?

Tags: integration

Be puzzling with this integral and wondering if an analytical solution exists. If it does, it has escaped me to date!
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\exp(\sin(x))+\exp(\cos(x))}\, dx.$$

Comment: A little scary...

Comment: Surprisingly, the result is "close" to $\pi$

Comment: Well, the function is continuous and bounded in $\;[0,2\pi]\;$, so the integral for sure exists. Now, what the primitive of that thing is is another, rather frightening, matter...

Comment: For what it is worth, the integrand can also be written $\frac12e^{-\sin(x)/\sqrt2}\text{ sech}(\cos(x)/\sqrt2)$.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer.*

The little scary problem gives (numerically)
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{\exp(\sin(x))+\exp(\cos(x))}=3.183807032899083924101596594681\cdots$$
which (thanks to inverse symbolic calculators) is "close" to
$$\frac{ -20+10 e+45 e^2-59 \sqrt{1+e}-23 \sqrt{1+e^2}+10 \pi -20 \pi ^2+2 \sqrt{1+\pi }+23
   \sqrt{1+\pi ^2}} {23 }$$ the relative error being $2.43\times 10^{-19}$ percent.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\exp(\sin(x))+\exp(\cos(x))}dx$$
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a\exp(\sin(x))+b\exp(\cos(x))}dx$$

---

$$\frac{dI(a,b)}{da}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{-\exp(\sin(x))}{\left[a\exp(\sin(x))+b\exp(\cos(x))\right]^2}dx$$
$$\frac{dI(a,b)}{db}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{-\exp(\cos(x))}{\left[a\exp(\sin(x))+b\exp(\cos(x))\right]^2}dx$$

---

$$-(I_a+I_b)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\exp(\sin(x))+\exp(\cos(x))}{\left[a\exp(\sin(x))+b\exp(\cos(x))\right]^2}dx$$
so at $(a,b)=(1,1)$ then $-(I_a+I_b)=I$. Maybe this can be manipulated and solved as a differential equation?

---

Also notice that using the well known rule:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$
we get:
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\exp(-\sin(x))+\exp(\cos(x))}dx$$